# Magento Error - SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user

Tags: magento

I had a `magento` site live and up and running and then out of nowhere I got:

```
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
```

After some research into the issue I changed a file name in /errors directory file: local.xml.sample to local.xml and got the following errors (pasted below) also in the title was written above the text pasted below.

The site was working fine, I was changing some shipping settings after installing a new shipping extension from WebShopapps and then all of a sudden this occurred. Not sure where to even start.

Trace:

```
#0 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/includes/src/__default.php(54845): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/includes/src/__default.php(55325): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/includes/src/__default.php(53532): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/includes/src/__default.php(54588): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/includes/src/__default.php(55433): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/includes/src/__default.php(29736): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/includes/src/__default.php(29677): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/includes/src/__default.php(12129): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/includes/src/__default.php(12159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/includes/src/__default.php(12144): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/includes/src/__default.php(12169): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/includes/src/__default.php(31766): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#12 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/includes/src/__default.php(23841): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#13 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/includes/src/__default.php(23873): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#14 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#15 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/includes/src/__default.php(5861): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#16 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/includes/src/__default.php(5866): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#17 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/includes/src/__default.php(20719): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#18 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/includes/src/__default.php(20577): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#19 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/includes/src/__default.php(20460): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#20 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/eyesocialeyes/public_html/tilebuyersoutlet/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Comment: Did you clear your cache and recompile after installing the extension?  Try temporarily disabling compilation (you can comment out `define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');` in `includes/config.php` and then clearing your cache manually.  See if that brings your site up - and based on your stack, double check your MySQL configuration/creds in local.xml.

Answer (score 1):

You installed a module but didn't disable cache and the compiler.

You need to manually clear the cache by deleting all the `var/cache/mage--?` subfolders

Then you need to disable the compiler by using SSH to run the following in your Magento root folder:

`php shell/compiler.php disable`

or if you don't have SSH access, find the `includes/config.php` file and comment out the following lines like so:

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

This should bring everything back. Log in, back out, then back into the Admin panel to load the new module completely and finish out your setups.

Leave compiler disabled till you've run a couple days without incident. Not all modules are compatible with the Compiler Kludge.